# mongodb and express error: Could not connect to database using connectionString

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-express

This was working last 3 months ago and now i check  its error. The error show that  `Could not connect to database using connectionString`

Already try this [Problem with connecting mongo express service in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68083050/problem-with-connecting-mongo-express-service-in-docker)

Docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  default:
    name: product-poc-project-net
    external: true

services:
  loggermicroservice:
    image: loggermicroservice
    container_name: loggermicroservice
    build:
     context: ./
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports: 
      - 8087:80
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    
    
      
    
    
   
 #----------------------------------------------------------------     
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: LoggerActivity
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - ./database-data:/data/db
#----------------------------------------------------------------   
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    container_name: mongo-express 
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:root@mongodb:27017/
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=LoggerActivity
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=root
```

Error 1

```
 Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:root@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express         | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mongodb
```

Error 2

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Answer (score 0):

fix in mongo-express side by removing `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017`

```
 environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:root@mongodb:27017/"
```